# Почему не открывается ссылка через System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

Tags: .net

Открываю через `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` ссылку и передаю в ней логин\пароль. Сайт открывается в браузере по-умолчанию. Перехожу в открытом окне на другую страницу сайта. Потом при повторном открытии из программы происходит переадресация на ту страницу, куда я перешел после первого открытия.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего сайт кэширует(запоминает) последний переход внутри сайта. Попробуйте явно указать страницу\каталог сайта.

Comment: Как сайт это делает? Это возможно предотвратить? Просто данные отправляю на страницу, с которой после авторизации происходит редирект на главную по-хорошему. А тут глюк.